# Trouble Receiving SMS OTP Code from Firebase in Flutter App on Specific Network Provider

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-api, sms, sms-gateway

I'm currently working on implementing OTP (One-Time Password) verification via Firebase in my Flutter app. Everything appears to be functioning correctly, and I can successfully receive SMS OTP codes. However, I've encountered an issue on a specific network provider where I'm not receiving any SMS messages, and I'm getting the following error:

[smsretrieverhelper] sms verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17499 error code:39

Can anyone offer insights or solutions for this network-specific SMS reception problem? Your help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

i try it on another network and it works fine
my region is jordan - middle east